# django ImageField empty after form post

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

When I upload a photo to django through form the image field is empty. I confirmed this by using `logging.info(form.cleaned_data['picture'] )`

I checked through the console that the form has `'multipart/form-data'`

The model :

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)        
    treatment_plan=models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=True)
    treatment_done=models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=True)        

    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='image', storage=DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

the modelForm :

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'age', 'martial_status', 'mobile', 'sex',
                  'amount_paid','amount_left','note', 'address','date','picture','treatment_done','treatment_plan','chief_complain']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': True, 'class': 'form-control',
                                             'placeholder': 'name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': True, 'class': 'form-control',
            'picture': forms.FileInput(attrs={'required': False,'class': 'form-control','enctype': 'multipart/form-data'}),
```

view.py :

```
def add_person(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'core/login.html')
    else: 
        form = PersonForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None,instance=Person())
        #form = PersonForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES )
        if form.is_valid():

            persons = form.save()

            persons.user = request.user
            #to capitalized the first letter so we have consistency when querying , this is a workaround since __iexact is not working
            persons.name=persons.name.title()
            persons.last_name=persons.last_name.title()
            logging.info(form.cleaned_data['last_name'] )

            persons.save()

            return redirect('home')
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'core/add_person.html', context)
```

The html template :

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
   <label for="address">{% trans "Address" %}</label>
   {{ form.address|add_class:"form-control" }}
  </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
   <label for="pic">{% trans "Picture" %}</label>
    {{form.picture}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Does your html template form has this attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Check `instance=Person()`: Your passing an new person instance to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but still, as far as I know the parameter "multipart/form-data" should be in the form, and not in input, and you install it to the FieldFile

```
'picture': forms.FileInput(attrs={'required': False,'class': 'form-control','enctype': 'multipart/form-data'}),
```